# How to align item to the bottom of the screen in J2ME Polish

Tags: java-me, vertical-alignment

How can I align an item to the bottom of the screen without using a FramedForm?

Answer (score -1):

May a quick look into this helps for aligning an item 
http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html

Comment: I've tried LAYOUT_BOTTOM without success. An example would be appreciated.